Docker returning Error 133: Failed to create temporary file with plenty of disk space
I am trying to build an image based on a public AWS image using a Makefile. The very first thing that the build process does is successfully pull that image. Immediately after pulling the image, I get the following failure:
assertion failed [!result.is_error]: Failed to create temporary file
(ThreadContextFcntl.cpp:84 create_tempfile)
 make: *** [xxxxxxxxx] Error 133

I am running this on a newer MacBook Pro with an M3 Max chip. Docker was installed with Homebrew, if that matters. My first assumption was that I didn't give enough resources to the daemon. However, I've increased the core count to the maximum allowed, given it 9GB of memory, 2GB of swap, and 496GB virtual disk limit. I still am seeing the failure, so I'm pretty sure it isn't a problem with the disk space limit. I haven't found anything else relating to exit code 133, except that it's based on the signal 5 exit code, which is SIGTRAP. I don't know how that helps me though. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Just to rule out the obvious: did you restart Docker after allocating more disk?

Yes, several times.

This is an issue with Docker Desktop and Rosetta emulation.
To fix, disable the setting Use Rosetta for x86_64/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon.
Source (where I found my resolution when coming upon this issue): https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/kyma-project/serverless/components/serverless#readme-symptom-1

Disabling Rosetta is, at best, a workaround, but it is by no means a solution to the problem. A real solution would have to come without a significant loss of performance (which is what disabling Rosetta will do).
